# Initiate CDbConnection with full set of parameters

Tags: php, database, yii

I need to initiate another (next to default one) database connection and I want to do this the very same way, as Yii does for configuration. I.e. to feed it with configuration array:

```
array
(
    'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
    'charset'=>'utf8',
    'username'=>'username',
    'password'=>'password',
    'emulatePrepare'=>true
)
```

And to be sure, that *all* `CDbConnection`'s properties will be correctly set.

But, [`CDbConnection::__construct`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#__construct-detail) accepts only `$dns`, `$username`, `$password` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way, I found so far, is to initiate `CDbConnection` with empty values and iterate through configuration array keys and set each by each:

```
$db = new CDbConnection();

foreach($config as $key->$value) {
    $db->$key = $value;
}

$db->active = true;
```

But, I have the feeling, that there should be a better way of doing this.